# JavaScript RegEx to match custom formatted code block

Tags: javascript, regex

The code looks like this:

```
{% for item in example %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Basically, I need three things in this code. The `item`, `example`, and the content of the code block. I'm using this expression:

```
^{% for (.*?) in (.*?) %}((.*?|\n)+){% endfor %}$
```

But if I have more than one code in that format, it matches the all from the first opening of `for` until the last closing of `endfor`. A screenshot might help explaining this:

[image: regex]

I also have it here: https://regex101.com/r/zD1vO9/3

Comment: You may need to look into non-greedy matching.  Not sure if JS supports it or not, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `?` after `+` to do a non-greedy match.

```
^{% for (.*?) in (.*?) %}((.*?|\n)+?){% endfor %}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zD1vO9/4)

**OR**

```
^{% for (.*?) in (.*?) %}([\s\S]+?){% endfor %}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zD1vO9/5)

Comment: nested statements was not possible.